# Making paid app to free app, how to identify existing users

Tags: android

I have a free version of my App (1300+ users) on Play store and a Paid version (40+ users) with more features. I want to make my Paid version free going forward and introduce in-App purchase instead, so that if people like the App, they won't mind spending a few bucks.

Now my problem is this. I want to take care of the users (40+) who already paid for the App when it was paid version. I want to give these users some extra stuff which otherwise is only available via in-App. How can I identify these paid users?

Please help.

-Abhi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With such a low number of paid users, you could offer a refund of the original charge if they paid for the in-app content. It is a good idea to keep all of your users the same and not treat a group differently. It makes things easier to manage in the future.

Comment: Sorry but I am looking for a technical solution to the problem at hand. Forget about the number of users for now :)

Comment: Assuming you are using the Google Licensing system, there is no technical solution. Once the app is made free, all users will be the same whether they have paid in the past or not.

Comment: That's true. I am using Google license system (publishing via PlayStore). In a generic sense, can I detect who is upgrading and who is installing fresh?

Comment: No. Even if you could, there would be no way to tell if a previously paid user was simply installing the app on another device or if it was a new user installing for the first time.

Comment: Ok I rest my case. Thanks!